# Getting specific Line values on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to access line values in a video. I've found how to print all the values on screen with the following code, but what I need is to print only when the value 255 (white) appears.

```
    LineIterator li1(fgThreshold, Point(20, 0), Point(20, 479), 8); 
    vector<Vec3b> buf1;
    for (int i = 0; i<li1.count; i++) { 
        buf1.push_back(Vec3b(*li1));
        li1++;
    }
    cout << Mat(buf1) << endl;
```

The reason is that I need to save the frame when the white color (generated by `threshold`) crosses the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on a *thresholded* image, then it's type is `CV_8UC1`, and its elements are `uchar`, not `Vec3b`.

In this case, you can check if the value of the line iterator is white (255) like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Create a CV_8UC1 Mat with a white circle
    // Your fgThreshold would be something like this
    Mat1b fgThreshold(100, 100, uchar(0));
    circle(fgThreshold, Point(20, 20), 3, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

    // Init line iterator
    LineIterator lit(fgThreshold, Point(20, 0), Point(20, 40));

    // Value to check
    const uchar white = 255;

    // Save colors in buf, if value is ok
    vector<uchar> buf;
    // Save points in pts, if value is ok
    vector<Point> pts;

    for (int i = 0; i < lit.count; ++i, ++lit)
    {
        // Check if value is ok
        if (**lit == white)
        {
            // Add to vectors
            buf.push_back(**lit);
            pts.push_back(lit.pos());
        }
    }

    // Print
    cout << "buf: " << Mat(buf) << endl;
    cout << "pts: " << Mat(pts) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In case you're working on `CV_8UC3` images, you need to cast the line iterator, like:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b fgThreshold(100, 100, Vec3b(0,0,0));
    circle(fgThreshold, Point(20, 20), 3, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);

    LineIterator lit(fgThreshold, Point(20, 0), Point(20, 40));

    const Vec3b white(255, 255, 255);

    vector<Vec3b> buf;
    vector<Point> pts;

    for (int i = 0; i < lit.count; ++i, ++lit)
    {
        // Cast to Vec3b
        if ((Vec3b)*lit == white)
        {
            // Cast to Vec3b
            buf.push_back((Vec3b)*lit);
            pts.push_back(lit.pos());
        }
    }

    cout << "buf: " << Mat(buf) << endl;
    cout << "pts: " << Mat(pts) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```